# Very basic Python web server - strange issue

Tags: python, webserver

I'm just starting out with Python and I'm trying to code a simple web server. Everything seems to be work except I'm having one small problem. When I request a specific file like Test.html from my web server, the data in the HTML file is repeated over and over in my client like its stuck in a loop. So instead of seeing just "Test" displayed in the web client once, I see "Test Test Test Test Test Test...many times over". This is probably a simple error but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks for you help!

```
import socket
import sys

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Socket Created!!")

try:
#bind the socket
    #fill in start
        server_address = ('localhost', 6789)
        serversocket.bind(server_address)
    #fill in end
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Bind failed. Error Code: " + str(msg[0]) + "Message: " + 
msg[1])
    sys.exit()  
print("Socket bind complete")

#start listening on the socket
#fill in start
serversocket.listen(1)
#fill in end
print('Socket now listening')

while True: 
#Establish the connection 
    connectionSocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
    print('source address:' + str(addr))
    try:
    #Receive message from the socket
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)  
        print('message = ' + str(message))
        #obtian the file name carried by the HTTP request message
        filename = message.split()[1] 
        print('filename = ' + str(filename))
        f = open(filename[1:], 'rb') 
        outputdata = f.read()
        #Send the HTTP response header line to the socket
        #fill in start
        connectionSocket.send(bytes('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n','UTF-
8'))
        #fill in end
        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):  
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata)

        #close the connectionSocket
        #fill in start
        connectionSocket.close()
        #fill in end

        print("Connection closed!")
    except IOError: 
        #Send response message for file not found 
        connectionSocket.send(bytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not 
Found\r\n\r\n","UTF-8"))
        connectionSocket.send(bytes("<html><head></head><body><h1>404 
Not Found</h1></body></html>\r\n","UTF-8"))

#Close the client socket 
        #fill in start
        connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: why would you do this? just `import flask`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stuck in a loop :)

```
    #fill in end
    #Send the content of the requested file to the client
    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):  
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
```

You're sending the contents of `outputdata` the number of times however long the length of the file is.

You only need `connectionSocket.send(outputdata)` without the for..loop to send it once.

Also, make sure you close the file you read the contents from. (`f.close()`)